# GraphQL query giving me a a "Cannot return null" error when I know data is in the database

Tags: graphql

Here's the data:

[image]

Here's my code.

```
const { idArg, queryType, stringArg } = require('@nexus/schema')
const { getUserId } = require('../utils')

const Query = queryType({
  definition(t) {
    t.field('users', {
      type: 'User',
      resolve: (parent, args, ctx) => {
        return ctx.prisma.user.findMany()
      },
    })

module.exports = {
  Query,
}
```

I know the database has users in the table, but here's what I get when I run the following query in playground.

```
query {
  users{
    id
  }
}

{
  "data": null,
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Cannot return null for non-nullable field User.id.",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 3,
          "column": 5
        }
      ],
      "path": [
        "users",
        "id"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: user records without id field?

Comment: Nope, I just added a screenshot of the data.

Comment: The type of your field is an object, not a list, but your resolver returns an array. There is no `id` property on the returned array, so GraphQL returns an error. You need to either change the type of your field to a list or return a single object inside your resolver.

Comment: To make a field a list in Nexus, you use `t.list.field` instead of `t.field`